# Redirect A URL with a number in it to the one without

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting, http-status-code-301

Does anyone know if there is an .htaccess rule to redirect from somthing like this...
XXX/dodge/**604**-jeep-hard-start-cold
to...
XXX/dodge/jeep-hard-start-cold
Basically wondering if there is some sort a variable that will remove the number from URL's.
All URL's have different numbers, so it cant just be the 604 getting a redirect.
It is a Joomla site, and numbers refer to article #.
Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to configure Joomla to not add the article number to the url of the article. You can turn on Search Enging Friendly urls in the Global Configuration.